# Count number of times value has appeared in last x rows in group

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe like the following

```
dataDF <- data.frame(
  group = c(rep('a', 10), rep('b', 10)),
  value = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3,
            3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1)
)
```

I want to find the number of times each value has appeared in the group for the past 5 entries (or if it has not had 5 rows yet then the total count so far ).

So I would end up with:

```
   group value number_l5
1      a     4         1
2      a     4         2
3      a     4         3
4      a     3         1
5      a     4         4
6      a     3         2
7      a     4         3
8      a     3         3
9      a     3         3
10     a     3         4
11     b     3         1
12     b     1         1
13     b     1         2
14     b     1         3
15     b     3         2
16     b     1         4
17     b     3         2
18     b     2         1
19     b     3         3
20     b     1         2
```

So the first three rows, the value is 4 for every row so the cumulative count is 1,2,3. The 4th row is the first time we see 3, so the count is 1. By the time you get past the 5th row we are only looking at the past five rows, so in row 7 we count the number of 4's from row 3 to 7, getting 3. Once you get to row 11 a new group 'b' starts and we begin again.

Would like to do with `dplyr` and `group_by` if possible

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Initially asked for proportion, to make simpler and hopefully more clear have changed to ask for number. Apologies for any confusion!

Comment: The conditions are not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zoo::rollapply` for this; Here set the window size as `5` and `partial=T` to include the first few elements; `sum(v == tail(v, 1))` is to calculate the number of times the last element has appeared in each window:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

dataDF %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(proportion = rollapply(value, 5, function(v) sum(v == tail(v, 1)), partial=T, align='right'))

# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
#   group value proportion
#   <fct> <dbl>      <int>
# 1 a         4          1
# 2 a         4          2
# 3 a         4          3
# 4 a         3          1
# 5 a         4          4
# 6 a         3          2
# 7 a         4          3
# 8 a         3          3
# 9 a         3          3
#10 a         3          4
#11 b         3          1
#12 b         1          1
#13 b         1          2
#14 b         1          3
#15 b         3          2
#16 b         1          4
#17 b         3          2
#18 b         2          1
#19 b         3          3
#20 b         1          2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataDF%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(i=1:n(),value1=list(value))%>%
  group_by(group,i)%>%
  mutate(proportion=mean(value==unlist(value1)[if(i<5)1:i else i:(i-4)]))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  select(-i,-value1)
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   group value proportion
   <fct> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 a        4.      1.00 
 2 a        4.      1.00 
 3 a        4.      1.00 
 4 a        3.      0.250
 5 a        4.      0.800
 6 a        3.      0.400
 7 a        4.      0.600
 8 a        3.      0.600
 9 a        3.      0.600
10 a        3.      0.800
11 b        3.      1.00 
12 b        1.      0.500
13 b        1.      0.667
14 b        1.      0.750
15 b        3.      0.400
16 b        1.      0.800
17 b        3.      0.400
18 b        2.      0.200
19 b        3.      0.600
20 b        1.      0.400
>
```